# How to handle Checkbox value in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I have the following example:

```
Private Sub setCheck(ByVal val1 As Boolean, ByVal val2 As Boolean, ByVal val3 As Boolean)
    With userForm1
        .checkboxOne.Value = val1
        .checkboxTwo.Value = val2
        .checkboxThree.Value = val3
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub checkboxOne_Change()
    Call setCheck(True, False, False)
End Sub

Private Sub checkboxTwo_Change()
    Call setCheck(False, True, False)
End Sub

Private Sub checkboxThree_Change()
    Call setCheck(False, False, True)
End Sub
```

It is possible to click a check only in one direction. That means, if I clicked the checkboxOne first time, I don't have the ability to check it again. What I need to do?

Comment: Why aren't you using OptionButtons?

Comment: @Comintern what is the difference?

Comment: Only one OptionButton in a group can be selected at one time, so you don't have to worry about making sure only one is "checked". They're designed for picking a single option out of a group - CheckBoxes aren't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem that you have is after a checkbox's value has been initialized setting it's value will cause the checkbox's `Click` and `Change` events to fire.  This causes an infinite loop which effectively locks the checkboxes.

[image]

### The way around this is to use a class variable to ignore subsequent calls to setCheck during an update.

```
Private EditMode As Boolean

Private Sub setCheck(ByVal val1 As Boolean, ByVal val2 As Boolean, ByVal val3 As Boolean)
    If Not EditMode Then
        EditMode = True
        With UserForm1
            .checkboxone.Value = val1
            .checkboxtwo.Value = val2
            .checkboxthree.Value = val3
        End With
        EditMode = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub checkboxOne_Change()
    setCheck True, False, False
End Sub

Private Sub checkboxTwo_Change()
    setCheck False, True, False
End Sub

Private Sub checkboxThree_Change()
    setCheck False, False, True
End Sub
```

Comment: You don't understand my problem. The user should have the possibility to check one of the checkboxes not only one time. That means for example the user clicks `checkboxOne` then when he clicks `checkboxTwo`the first checkbox loses its value (set to false). Well, when the user clicks `checkboxOne` again then the second checkbox loses its value and the first checkbox gets the value back (set to true).

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
Private Sub chkbx1_Click()
    chkbx1.Enabled = False
    chkbx1.Value = Checked
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()

    Dim ctrl As Control

    ' reset it whenever you open the form. this could also be defined separately in the F4-properties of the checkbox
    For Each ctrl In Me.Controls
        If TypeName(ctrl) = "CheckBox" Then 
            ctrl.Enabled = True
            ctrl.Value = False
        End If
    Next ctrl

End Sub
```

Not quite sure if you really want the checkbock disabled but with the `Checked` value per se...

Comment: Whenever the user opens the form all checkboxes are set to false because the user need to know which one need to check. And the checkboxes mustn't be disabled.

Comment: hm, well, adjusted my code to do just that, however: from your description you want `i.` enabled, unchecked checkboxes when opening the form and `ii.` disabled checkboxes once the user clicks a checkbox ONCE. That means: per definition, once it's locked the checkbox can only have `.Value = Checked`... so is there really a point in locking it?

Answer (score 0):

since you're asking for mutually excluding control, you want Option Buttons

say you place three of them called "OptionButton1", "OptionButton2" and ""OptionButton3" then you will place the following in the Userform code pane:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub OptionButton1_Click()
    CheckOBs
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton2_Click()
    CheckOBs
End Sub

Private Sub OptionButton3_Click()
    CheckOBs
End Sub


Sub CheckOBs()
    Dim iOB As Integer

    For iOB = 1 To CInt(Right(ActiveControl.Name, 1))
        Controls("OptionButton" & iOB).Enabled = False
    Next iOB
End Sub
```